# TypeScript async iterate on object error

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Can someone explain me why this code give me error?

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
});

async function doSomethingAsync() {
    var data = await promise;
    data.forEach(v => console.log(v));
}

doSomethingAsync();
```

When i try to compile this like tsc file.ts --target ES6 i have this:

`error:async.ts(7,10): error TS2339: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: What happens if you change `new Promise(...)` to `new Promise<number[]>(...)`? Perhaps the type checker simply cannot infer a sufficiently specific type for `promise`?

Comment: By the way, aren't `async` and `await` es7 features?

Comment: They are, but AFAIK they are not actually stable and it will be changed in future (im not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i found solution
, We can just simply add a generic type into our Promise like:

```
'use strict';

var promise = new Promise<any[]>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(["gdfgdfgdf", "dfggfd", 1, 2, {}]);
});

async function doSomethingAsync() {
    let data = await promise;

    for (let i of data) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

doSomethingAsync();
```

Now it works perfectly without any mess in code :)

Comment: I see, so the type checker just needed to know that your promise would be resolved with an array. Nice find!